# Size Font to Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a suitable font size for my page. I currently have it set at `-webkit-xxx-large` as that fits my window perfectly.

What I need is the text to fit inside the window width (not fussed about height) no matter what the window size.

Example:
    1920px Window Width - `font-size: -webkit-xxx-large`
    480px Window Width - `font-size: large`

Whether it uses Javascript/jQuery or if it's just CSS it doesn't bother me. I just need a suitable one-size-for-all.

Comment: look at media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) using [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) like ([IE support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Browser_compatibility))

```
body {
    font-size: -webkit-xxx-large
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font-size: large;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KmUX2/) - reduce the width of the result panel

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the size constants. Find a value based on the `em` scale and that will work for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Text can be a pain to size exactly. [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/) is a nice Javascript Library that can size it to 1/100th of an em for you pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into something like: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Although i would not recommend this for your body text as media queries would probably suffice and give you more control. Smaller on small screens is not always better.